# $\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { { x }^{ t }-1 }{ \ln { x } } dx } $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do I solve the following integral:

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { { x }^{ t }-1}{ \ln { x }  } dx } $$

Comment: What is $t$? An integer, rational, real, complex, ... Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

By replacing $x$ with $e^{-u}$, we have:

$$ I(t)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^t-1}{\log x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}-e^{-u(t+1)}}{u}\,du = \color{red}{\log(t+1)}\tag{1}$$
by [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html). Another chance is given by differentiation under the integral sign:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\,I(t) = \int_{0}^{1}x^t\,dx =\frac{1}{t+1}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: [Proof of Frullani's theorem can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f2z58boupqu5uwz/Frullani_Integral.pdf?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The integral satisfies

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^1 \frac{x^t - 1}{\log x} dx
 = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{x^t - 1}{\log x}\right) dx = \int_0^1 x^t \,dx$$